# How to rotate locally in Y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I have character control like astronaut in zero gravity but I want to rotate it locally in y axis but it can't rotate. I tried rotating it in y axis but the player is rotating relative to world. i want it relative to the object. thanks for help.

here is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Astronaut : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static AstronautControls astronautControls;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float force;
    public float torque;
    public Vector2 move;
    float rotateHorizontal;
    float rotateVertical;
    float upDown;
    public PlayerInput playerInput;

    private void Awake()
    {
        astronautControls = new AstronautControls();
    }


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        astronautControls.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        astronautControls.Disable();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
        MoveUpDown();
        RotateHorizontal();
        RotateVertical();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        move = playerInput.actions["Move"].ReadValue<Vector2>();
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * force * move.y * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.AddForce(transform.right * force * move.x * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * force * upDown * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void MoveUpDown()
    {
        upDown = playerInput.actions["MoveVertical"].ReadValue<float>();
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * force * upDown * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void RotateHorizontal()
    {
        rotateHorizontal = playerInput.actions["RotateHorizontal"].ReadValue<float>();
        MouseLook.Z += rotateHorizontal;
    }

    //here is the problem when i rotate it seems it has gimbal lock or something i want local rotate relative to the player
    private void RotateVertical()
    {
        rotateVertical = playerInput.actions["RotateVertical"].ReadValue<float>();
        MouseLook.Y += rotateVertical;
    }
}
```

and here is the mouse look

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mouse mouse;
    public static float X;
    public static float Y;
    public static float Z;
    const float MIN_X = -90f;
    const float MAX_X = 90f;
    const float MIN_Y = -180f;
    const float MAX_Y = 180f;
    public static Vector3 euler;

    public float Sensitivity;
 
    void Awake()
    {
        mouse = Mouse.current;
        euler = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        X = euler.x;
        Y = euler.y;
        Z = euler.z;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        X -= mouse.delta.y.ReadValue() * (Sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
        if (X < MIN_X) X = MIN_X;
        else if (X > MAX_X) X = MAX_X;
        Y += mouse.delta.x.ReadValue() * (Sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Y < MIN_Y) Y = MIN_Y;
        else if (Y > MAX_Y) Y = MAX_Y;
        transform.parent.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(X, Y, Z);
    }
}
```

settings for my rigidbody

[image]

Comment: Can you not use something like [`RotateAround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) and pass in the parent's local `transform.Up` for the second parameter? `transform.RotateAround(transform.position, parent.transform.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);`. The other options is to use `transform.Rotate(0, yRotation, 0, Space.Self);` as `Space.Self` should result in rotating the object in its local space, not world space.

Comment: As it didn't fit in my last comment, the last way you could go about this is to multiply the original angle by the changed angle `transform.rotation = originAngle * Quaternion.Euler(xRotationChange, yRotationChange, zRotationChange);`.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned a few solutions on how to rotate an object in local space, but I believe the one that should work for your implementation would be the last one. To showcase it working, here is a simple test script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float changeInX = 0f;
    private float changeInY = 10f;
    private float changeInZ = 0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(changeInX, changeInY, changeInZ);
        }
    }
}
```

All it will do is rotate an object whenever the `Space` key is pressed. The object I have set up with this script is childed to a rotated object. Here is a gif showing the one cube childed to another rotating around its local Y-axis.

[image: Example]

If you would like all axes to rotate locally, I believe inserting a `changeInX` and `changeInZ` will result in similar results to the gif, where the rotations are applied locally.

Comment: Hello thanks for answer but I want to rotate the parent object and the child. the parent transform should inherit the rotation of the child like when I mouse look at the child camera  the player parent should also reflect the rotation. and also when changing the parent rotation the child camera should also change same to parent.

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII Sorry misunderstood your question. The snippet should still work. Instead of changing the child's rotation, change the parent's rotation with the snippet, and the child, as it is childed will follow without needing to do anything.

Comment: Or I might still be a bit confused as to what you would like to achieve. Do you want the parent object to assume the local rotation of the child, then for the child to rotate with the parent?

Comment: yes the my code above work on z axis and also when the player y is up it is also working but when i look down 45 degrees down with mouse look then the rotation is starting to become local world.

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII I'm still a bit lost. You have a parent/child relationship between two objects. If I understand you correctly, do you want the parent object to rotate relative to the child's orientation? When you rotate the parent, the child will also rotate as it is childed unless you counter-rotate. And what do you mean by `starting to become local world`? When manipulating transform, it is relative so unless you alternate between how you apply a change, it should consistently be in the same relative space.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Yes I want the same rotation I have a mouse look script its working fine but instead of only the camera rotating in mouse look i want also the parent of the camera to follow the camera orientation and its working fine. but the problem is I want to control the euler angle individually using keypress and add that but the rotation is the same as mouse look when you change angle separatly.

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII Sorry been rather busy. Are you saying you want to be able to spin the parent object over time on a singular axis relative to the child? Or relative to the parent? Due to the child being well childed to the parent, moving the parent rotation will cause the child rotation to move with it.

Comment: the rotation is the same with child parent the problem is when you look down 45 degress and rotate it rotate as the axis arrow is like creating a circle in the ground around the player. I want to rotate when you look down 45% the rotation like when 0% the arrow is in the front and in 180% is in the back pointing in the sky not in ground.

Comment: Can you upload a gif or video of what you mean exactly? Are you experiencing gimbal lock?